# Can unsweetened cranberry juice be used to pickle food

Tags: pickling, cranberries

I have always been fascinated by pickled foods.

Cranberry juice has a very low PH and I was curious if it can be used as a pickling agent.

Has anyone tried cranberry pickled cucumbers and tomatoes or cranberry pickled fish/cranberry pickled eggs?

Comment: Please try - and report back with your results! :)

Comment: @brhans see my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsweetened cranberry juice would be perfectly fine for making quick/refrigerator pickles.

If you want to make safe shelf stable pickles, you would need to know for sure that the cranberry juice’s pH is the same or lower than the vinegar that is called for in the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

It’s really not as tart as I was expecting. Tasted pretty sour like a normal vinegar pickle.

I used cranberry juice, kosher salt and some iodized salt.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I have never seen this done so I don’t believe that it is possible, or that it would turn out so good. Though I am sure you could try it out based on the fact I have never seen it done I don’t believe that it would be the best idea. I have found you can pickle cranberries though if that helps haha

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SA!  We appreciate that you tried to answer a question that nobody else had the answer to.  As part of the Stack Exchange network, askers expect answers that either have citations or direct personal experience.  For that reason, your answer may not receive any upvotes.  Please keep answering, maybe take on a question on a topic you know well.